# Is there a vectorized way to access values of column explicitely indicated in another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I apologize if this questions has been asked before, it seems quite trivial, but somehow I cannot find the answer.

Let's say that I have a column (`selected`) that contains the name of another column (`option_1`, `option_2`, `option_3`, `option_4`):

```
    id  option_1    option_2    option_3    option_4    selected
0   0   10.0        NaN         NaN         110.0       option_4
1   1   NaN         20.0        200.0       NaN         option_2
2   2   NaN         300.0       30.0        NaN         option_3
3   3   400.0       NaN         NaN         40.0        option_1
4   4   600.0       700.0       50.0        50.0        option_3
```

So, for example, for the 1st row (`id==0`), the `selected` column indicate that the value is stored in `option_4` (i.e. 110.0), for 2nd row, it is stored in `option_2`, etc.

**Is there a vectorized way (e.g. without using apply) in which I could obtain a new series (column) with just the values indicated in the `selected` column?**

This seems to be such a common case that I find it difficult to believe that there is no other way than using apply, specially considering that methods such as [`idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html) and [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) returns exactly columns in that format.

---

### Example of how to achieve the result using apply

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [0,1,2,3,4], 
    'option_1': [10,     np.nan, np.nan, 400,    600], 
    'option_2': [np.nan, 20,     300,    np.nan, 700], 
    'option_3': [np.nan, 200,    30,     np.nan, 50],
    'option_4': [110,    np.nan, np.nan, 40,     50], 
    'selected': ['option_4','option_2','option_3','option_1','option_3']
})
df['value'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[x['selected']], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

```
df['value'] = df.lookup(df.index, df['selected'])
print (df)
   id  option_1  option_2  option_3  option_4  selected  value
0   0      10.0       NaN       NaN     110.0  option_4  110.0
1   1       NaN      20.0     200.0       NaN  option_2   20.0
2   2       NaN     300.0      30.0       NaN  option_3   30.0
3   3     400.0       NaN       NaN      40.0  option_1  400.0
4   4     600.0     700.0      50.0      50.0  option_3   50.0
```

Comment: @jesrael, I used your answer and noticed that my code was even slower. After some testing, I am finding that `min` is faster than `lookup` (see a [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51934952/why-is-df-lookup-slower-than-df-min)). Do you have an idea what could I missing?

Comment: @toto_tico Hard question, I am not pandas developer. Maybe problem pandas is more optimalized for a few number of columns and large number od rows.